# How can i make sure that my azure subscription uses credits from azure sponshorship?

Tags: azure, azureportal

I have Azure sponsorship and we have moved it to our current Azure PAYG subscription. How can I make sure that the services/ resources that are already in Azure are using sponsorship credits instead of a PAYG subscription?

[Recent subscriprions/ sponsorships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gypu3.png)

[Sponsorship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxO6V.png)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new resource, select your Sponsorship subscription from the Subscription dropdown.

Comment: Yep, i know i can do it this way, but is it possible to change payment from subscription to sponsorship credits for all resources? I dont want to use PAYG but those credits

Comment: No, your credits are tied to the account they were assigned to. Contact Azure support if you want to transfer them to your other account.